# Como posicionar un depliegue de navbar sobre un div con imagen

Tags: html, css

estoy aprendiendo css y tengo un problema con mi proyeccto usando guias cree un navbar responsinve pero en algunas partes no se superpone a div o formularios   cuando  se ve en responsive. En mi pantalla principal cuando se deberia desplegar el navbar se queda por detrás de una imagen y no se puede usar y cuando intento desplegar en modo responsive en un formulario muestra lo demas pero no se superpone a un  custom-file-label.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  scroll-beaviour: smooth;

}

.main-container {
  position: relative;
}


.banner-img {
  background: url(../img/learning2.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;

  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.banner-content {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="banner-img">
        <div class="banner-content">
            <h2 class="title">Alfabetizacion <span>Digital</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Ademas quisiera que siempre el navbar se superponga a cualquier elemento en la pagina

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
}

.nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  position: relative;
}

.nav > .nav-header {
  display: inline;
}

.nav > .nav-header > .nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav > .nav-btn {
  display: none;
}

.nav > .nav-links {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efefef;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a:hover {
  background-color:#eee;
  color: #333;
}

.nav > #nav-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .nav > .nav-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label:hover,.nav  #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-btn > label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label > span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:not(:checked) ~ .nav-links {
    height: 0px;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>


    <div class="nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
  <div class="nav-header">
    <div class="nav-title">
     TeEnseño
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-btn">
    <label for="nav-check">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav-links">

    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Portada">Inicio</a>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Register">Registro</a>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Post">Post</a>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Login" >Login</a>
    
  </div>
</div>


    </header>
```

Se los agradecería muchísimo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `z-index` para poner el navbar adelante de la imagen.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  scroll-beaviour: smooth;
}

.main-container {
  position: relative;
}

.banner-img {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/09/16/05/forest-931706_1280.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-content {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "segoe ui";
}

.nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  position: relative;
}

.nav>.nav-header {
  display: inline;
}

.nav>.nav-header>.nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav>.nav-btn {
  display: none;
}

.nav>.nav-links {
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav>.nav-links>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efefef;
}

.nav>.nav-links>a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
}

.nav>#nav-check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav>.nav-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav>.nav-btn>label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav>.nav-btn>label:hover,
  .nav #nav-check:checked~.nav-btn>label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .nav>.nav-btn>label>span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  }
  .nav>.nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  .nav>.nav-links>a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav>#nav-check:not(:checked)~.nav-links {
    height: 0px;
  }
  .nav>#nav-check:checked~.nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="nav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
    <div class="nav-header">
      <div class="nav-title">
        TeEnseño
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-btn">
      <label for="nav-check">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="nav-links">

      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Portada">Inicio</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Blog">Blog</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Register">Registro</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Post">Post</a>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/Login">Login</a>

    </div>
  </div>

</header>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="banner-img">
    <div class="banner-content">
      <h2 class="title">Alfabetizacion <span>Digital</span></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```